# How to combine repositories into a single one in Bazaar?

Tags: merge, bazaar

I have three independent Bazaar repositories. They are all related to a single project but have no overlapping files.

I want to combine them into a single repository, under different sub-folders, and preserve their history.

Is this possible? Note that I don't want to maintain the independent nature of the repositories. It will be a one time operation.

There is a solution for doing this in GIT:  [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories) But I couldnt find something similar for Bazaar.

**What I have tried:**
I tried merging the repositories, but files that have common paths in the two repositories cause conflicts. I would like them to be merged under different sub-directories but couldn't figure out how. I mostly use Bazaar in a non-collaborative way; I am not familiar with the `merge` command.

**Update**: I found [a bzr plugin](https://launchpad.net/bzr-merge-into/+index) which aims to do exactly what I want, but is buggy.

Comment: Have you tried the `bzr join` command?

Comment: Yes, I did try. And hit this bug/feature: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/370710

Comment: Have you tried upgrading before running "bzr join" ?

Comment: Yes @jelmer, I did try upgrading. I even tried downgrading to an older format. I have even tried assigning unique root ids to the different repositories using a python script. I have tried cascading the joins as well. That is `A` join with `B`, then join that merger with `C`, etc. It was a whole day of experimentation, but no dice.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `merge -r0..-1` command. But if you want to put files into different subfolders, it's better to do that before merge.

Let's say you have one `main` component, and 2 subcomponents: `foo` and `bar`. You want your new combined project to have the following structure:

```
ProjectRoot/
    main.txt     <-- any files from main component 
    ...               should be at the root of the project
    ...
    bar/         <-- bar subdirectory with files from bar component
    foo/         <-- foo subdirectory with files from foo component
```

We will merge `foo` and `bar` into `main`. But first let's move files into subdirectories:

```
cd /path/to/foo
bzr mkdir foo
bzr mv file1 file2 foo
bzr commit -m "files moved into foo/ subdirectory"
```

And similar for `bar`:

```
cd /path/to/bar
bzr mkdir bar
bzr mv file3 file4 bar
bzr commit -m "files moved into bar/ subdirectory"
```

Now we're ready to merge everything into `main`:

```
cd /path/to/main
# ensure the working tree does not have uncommitted changes
bzr status
# now merge foo
bzr merge -r0..-1 /path/to/foo
# if there is no conflicts then you can commit this part
bzr status
bzr commit -m "merged foo component"
# now merge bar
bzr merge -r0..-1 /path/to/bar
# if there is no conflicts then you can commit this part
bzr status
bzr commit -m "merged bar component"
```

After that your `main` will have both `foo` and `bar` merged.

Comment: Thanks @bialix but this runs into the same problem: it creates conflicts between project files which are supposed to be different. In my case it is happening only with the last merge, so I may bite the bullet and forego the commit history for that last repository.

Comment: @HRJ: you can use bzr-fastimport plugin to convert your third repo into 1.14 format (non rich-root) and then merge it again.

Answer (score 0):

Appears there's a plugin for this, at least for bazaar (as opposed to breezy), as of writing (July 2021) - https://launchpad.net/bzr-merge-into